# cant find phone

Tags: contact-shortcut

I cant find the location of my phone but I need the contacts on the phone so that I can conduct business.  I did not set the android phone up with an email account
Is there a way to get the contacts with just my phone number if the phone is still on and going to voicemail

Answer (score 0):

If you had lost it somewhere in where you live, you can call it using another phone and it should play its ringtone somewhere near you. However, if you lost it in a large, public area, that may be a bit of a problem. You can try to track it using its phone number, however depending on where you live, it may be illegal. (Use this site: https://www.aclu.org/map/cell-phone-location-tracking-laws-state to help you.) However if it is not illegal, Google will be your friend in this situation.